# Three.js - how to get direction to a vertex in shader

Tags: javascript, vector, three.js, glsl, direction

I'm writing my custom shader for atmosphere simulation (using https://github.com/wwwtyro/glsl-atmosphere sample). First, I added this shader without any changing to the sphere geometry, and I got my sky sphere, it is just what I wanted it to be :)

[image]

So, the source code of glsl-atmosphere works so: there is a function, called atmosphere, which returns the color of a pixel for atmosphere in a custom direction.

I send the local vertex coordinates of my sphere to the fragment shader. Because the sphere is centered in 0,0,0, I can get the eye direction by using just these interpolated vertex coordinates. I evaluate the atmosphere function with the direction equal to this interpolated vertex position.

this is the "outside" view of a sphere:
[image]

The next step is to realize the aerial perspective. Aerial perpsective makes objects far away to get the color of atmosphere (like mountains far away become blue-ish). The equation from https://www.scratchapixel.com/lessons/procedural-generation-virtual-worlds/simulating-sky/simulating-colors-of-the-sky:

```
FinalColor = ObjectColor*(1.0-BlendFactor)+skyColor
```

ObjectColor is the color (texture), blendfactor is a value from 0 to 1, and skyColor is what the atmosphere function returns (see code on github link above).

So I need to get the color of the atmosphere in the direction of each vertex in my terrain (or any other geometry which I will add to the scene). But now I can't just take local vertex coordinates to get the direction vector. I need a vector which shows the direction from camera to the terrain vertex, but I don't know how to do it.

For testing, I decided to apply some sample shader to my terrain without texturing, so I used the formula FinalColor=SkyColor. Logically, because the directions are the same, the terrain should be invisible, the colors of both the terrain and the sphere must be the same.

I tried this formula:

```
eyedir = (modelMatrix*vec4(position,1.0)).xyz-myPos; // in vertex shader
```

and then, use `atmosphere(eyedir,...)` to get the direction in the fragment shader.

The problem is I can't send just the view direction (which I can get from the camera object), because then all the vertices will be of one color, so this direction should change from vertex to vertex.

Could you give me some advice about how to evaluate this direction vector?

With best regards,

RealCoder

P. S. By the way, if I place the camera in 0,0,0, then it works as it suggested.

But when I'm moving, I begin to see the ghost terrain :)

At the beginning:

[image]

When I moved a few:

[image]